# Jquery code inside each.(function) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is Js code

```
$(".productwrapcart").each(function(){
  var addbg = $(this).find(".cartfeat img").attr('src');
  $(this).find(".incartbttn").css('background-image','url(' + addbg + ')');                        
});
```

The idea is for js to pull content from a hidden table in the item of multiple similar items loop.

For some reason, code inside this piece of code doesn't work.

```
$(".productwrapcart").each(function(){});
```

As soon as i put it outside, it starts working...

Comment: That means `.productwrapcart` doesn't match any elements, so there's no `each` to run.

Comment: Run ```$(".productwrapcart")``` in console of the browser and check what is the results.

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Nothing happens? Or something happens but not what you expect? Or...?

Comment: OK, well I think you'll need to show a sample of your html. Consider also providing a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: weird. in simplified version it works...   http://jsfiddle.net/ov3nos9g/

Comment: Try console.log($(".productwrapcart").length)